# Connecting 10G SFP+ slot to 1G SFP slot

Tags: switch, sfp

Will connecting a switch operating in fixed 10GB mode and SFP+ slot and SFP+ module,
to:
A server's network adapter operating in fixed 1GB mode with SFP+ slot and SFP+ module result in damage to the SFP transceiver modules and the switch/Network Adapter involved ?

Both connectors have spf+ modules, but operate in different fixed modes, as configured from the switch, server network adapter themselves.

According to my understanding the possible damage extent is from SFP module to SFP module and the switch and network adapter will not be damaged, however a clarification is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, no damage is possible.

Using compatible SFP+ modules between two ports but with one of them fixed to 10G and one to 1G (requires a dual-speed module) simply won't work. Both sides need to use the same speed or a set of speeds with some intersection.

Comment: I meant both connectors have spf+ modules, but operate in different fixed modes, as configured from the switch, server network adapter themselves. Edited.

Comment: I understand that in all cases, even those not described here, trying a connection with different fixed speeds either with SPF or SPF+ ports and with SPF or SPF+ modules from either side, or from both ends or mix of them will simply not work and will not result in any damage. Did I understand correctly ?

Comment: Generally, yes. While there are a few exceptions (matching APC with (U/S)PC fiber connectors, excessive receiver blinding with extended-range transmitters), you can't usually damage anything.

Comment: Does the inability to do harm to the equipment happen because both ends need to try negotiate common speed before they operate normally and that negotiation is harmless, even with SPF module inserted in SPF+ port, and vice versa no matter pre configured speed ?

Comment: A port configured with a fixed speed doesn't negotiate speed. It links at that speed or doesn't.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help. Now I understand.